# what does "Upset" means in this headline?

Tags: meaning

the headline is:

"American Women Upset Sprint Relay at World Championships"

how to interpret "upset" in this?

Comment: Warning: Google search for exact text results in "Malwarebytes Browser Guard blocked this website because it may contain malware activity." In sports journalism an 'upset' is a very surprising result of some match, game, race, etc.

Comment: You should say which on newspaper or journal web site you saw this headline.

Comment: Please see my answer before downvoting.

Answer (score 1):

This is a better question than it seems. Several online dictionaries define the idea correctly *only* for its noun form. E.g., [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/upset):

> an occasion when someone beats the team or player that was expected to win

I had to check [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/upset) before finding the correct definition for the verb:

> 4. to defeat or overthrow, usually unexpectedly

Comment: thank you for your reply. What I found confusing in it was the fact the "Upset" is not linked to a "Team "or a "player" directly. I din't know English could have this structure get it?

Comment: @Dagaggio lera I do get it. I think I have never seen it used in this way.

Comment: @Dagaggiolera  "upset" is linked to a team: "American women".  The American women in question are the team who upset the competition.

Comment: @stangdon, thank you for your reply, here is my understanding when I said the "Upset" should be linked to a "Team" or "player" I meant "upset" should act upon it, so, where there is " Upset Sprint Relay" the "Sprint Relay" part should be a "Team" or a "player"

Comment: @Dagaggiolera  I think I understand your question now.  It is possible to say, for example, "The Bulls *upset* the Rangers", but the object of *upset* doesn't have to be a team or a player; in this case it is the entire competition.

Comment: @stangdon, thank you a lot I wasn't aware of what "upset" object should be. One last question though, I saw in google translator that one definition of "upset" would be "contradict", so do you think in the headline there would be a possibility of this definition is being used? If not in this headline could I rephrase that headline so "upset" would mean contradict?

Comment: @Dagaggiolera I don't understand how "upset" could mean "contradict".  Can you provide a link for that?

Comment: @stangdon, the source was google translator, translating from portugues to english. I think that may have been lack of accuracy from google tool. (Not impossible LOL), still I have some difficult in wrap my head around the idea American Women can upset the entire competition Imean someone can upset a match not the entire competition right?